# Solving equations by iteration (Calculator ANS key)

Tags: calculator

As I understand the iterations method, 
if we have an equation in the form of $x = f(x)$, and an initial guess $x_0$, in each step we plug in the x from the prev. iteration into $f(x)$.

Now lets consider this equation:
$$5-x = 2(8x-x^2)$$

if I re-write it in the form of:
$$x = 5-2(8x-x^2), $$
the solution diverges to infinity.

But, if I re-write it in the form of:
$$x = (5+2x^2)/17, $$
I get the solution after few iterations: $0.305066$

How come the solution is different even though it is still the same equation?
Thank you!

Comment: This is called **fixed point iteration**, and your observation is correct: it doesn't always converge. I'm sure you'll get a good answer in a few, but just in case, you can google the term

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick answer that will skip some nuance.

For a map $x\mapsto f(x)$ with a fixed point $f(x^*)=x^*$, there are conditions that will cause the forward trajectory (i.e., keep hitting ANS) to converge to $x^*$. The main one is that you need $|f'(x^*)| < 1$. You also need your initial guess $x_0$ to be in the *basin of attraction* of $x^*$, which can introduce some interesting subtlety. So let's check out your two equations:

Let $f_1(x)=5-2(8x-x^2)$. Solving $f(x^*)=x^*$ gives $x^* = \frac{17}{4}\pm \frac{\sqrt{249}}{4}$, or $x^*\approx 0.305$ and $x^*\approx 8.195$.. Evaluating $f_1'(x^*)$, we get $f_1'(x^*)\approx -14.8$ and $f_1'(x^*)\approx 16.8$ for each of the two fixed points. By the criterion I gave above, this means the process will not converge.

On the other hand, for $f_2(x)=\frac{5+2x^2}{17}$, even thought we have the same fixed point $x^*\approx 0.305$, we have $f'(x^*)\approx 0.07$. This means the process *will* converge by the same criterion.

Comment: Nice! but, If I do not know the solution, how do I know where to check if the magnitude of the derivative < 1?
Until I discovered the iteration method I was using table mode on the calculator (g(x) = 0) and then looking where it switch sign, something like binary search, decreasing the range on each iteration

Comment: You can just solve the equation $x=f(x)$ for $x$. For your example, you can use the quadratic equation, although I used Mathematica to save time.

Comment: @user3475612, check for your initial guess

Comment: One more thing, 
If I input the form that *didn't* converge by repeatedly pressing Ans, as an equation of X and use the SOLVE (CALC) button, It does find a solution, even though I used the same form and same initial value. Does the calculator use another method of iteration?

Comment: @user3475612, yes. There are more robust methods. Like Newton-Raphson method